# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, linker-errors

I get a Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error when compile it.

I build a game tree and check which nodes of the tree is empty using `isEmpty()` function.

Although there shows no errors,im not sure about the way i pass the two-dimensional array tree into the `isEmpty()` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include "header.h"
#define YES 10
#define NO 20

struct Node
{
    Node ** children;
    int     childCount;
    char name[1];
    int empty;//YES or NO
    int sequence;
    double  value;
};

using namespace std;

bool isEmpty(Node, int);

bool isEmpty(Node **ptr, int bsize) {    
    for (int i = 0; i<bsize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bsize; j++) {
            if((*(ptr+i)+j)->empty == YES){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int size  = 4;
    Node tree[size][size];
// some stuff
    if (isEmpty(tree[size][size], size)) {
        cout<<"this is empty\n";
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this error?
Any help plz..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isEmpty` function prototype doesn't match your `isEmpty` definition.

Unfortunately, C++ isn't very friendly when it comes to passing multidimensional arrays to functions.  Your options are:

1. Drop the arrays and user pointers instead.  You'll have to use dynamic allocation instead.
2. Rather than using a 2 dimensional array, use a 1D one of size `(length * width)`.
3. Use universally fixed sizes for your arrays.

Number 2 is probably easiest.  Code:

```
#define YES 10
#define NO 20
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    Node ** children;
    int     childCount;
    char name[1];
    int empty;//YES or NO
    int sequence;
    double  value;
};

using namespace std;

bool isEmpty(Node ptr[], int bsize) {    
    for (int i = 0; i<bsize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bsize; j++) {
            if(ptr[i * bsize + j].empty == YES){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int size  = 4;
    Node tree[size * size];
// some stuff
    if (isEmpty(tree, size)) {
        cout<<"this is empty\n";
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone for method 1](http://ideone.com/C1tg3B)
[Ideone for method 3](http://ideone.com/Y80yZB)

Comment: After I modified it, another error occurs:No matching function for call to 'isEmpty' at     if (isEmpty(tree[size][size], size)) {

Comment: Also, I'd use `#define YES true` and `define NO false` instead of inventing new wheels.